# Can I get just the list of network interfaces from ip?

Tags: command-line, ip

I am looking to retrieve a list of network interfaces.

Currently I am returning the results of `ip addr` and then doing some regex/string searching from output like this:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 
84: eth0@if85: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.2/16 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:acff:fe11:2/64 scope link tentative 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I don't really care about all the meta data, I am just looking for the interface names. So I would like to instead get:

```
1: lo
84: eth0@if85
```

Is there a way to filter the results of the `ip addr` command? I can definitely do some other cli magic or just regex magic in my app, but it'd be nice to have `ip` itself filter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Using `grep` with PCRE(`-P`):

```
ip addr | grep -Po '^\d+:\s+\K[^:]+'
```

- `^\d+:\s+` matched the portion before interface name at the start, `\K` discards the match
- `[^:]+` gets the portion upto the next `:` i.e. the interface name

Similar logic using `sed`:

```
ip addr | sed -nE 's/^[[:digit:]]+:[[:blank:]]+([^:]+).*/\1/p'
```

On my system:

```
% ip addr | grep -Po '^\d+:\s+\K[^:]+'
lo
eth0
wlan0

% ip addr | sed -nE 's/^[[:digit:]]+:[[:blank:]]+([^:]+).*/\1/p'
lo
eth0
wlan0
```

---

**What you should really do:**

Linux kernel provides an interface for peeking into the hardware, it is `sysfs`, mounted on `/sys`.

You can get the interface name by just getting to the appropriate location of `/sys`, `/sys/class/net/` directory precisely.

On my system:

```
% ls -1 /sys/class/net/
eth0
lo
wlan0
```

Each of these are directories, with the subdirectories containing files and directories having all the info regarding the interface.

Here's the listing of the contents of `/sys/class/net/eth0` directory:

```
% ls -1 /sys/class/net/eth0                                    
addr_assign_type
address
addr_len
broadcast
carrier
carrier_changes
device
dev_id
dev_port
dormant
duplex
flags
gro_flush_timeout
ifalias
ifindex
iflink
link_mode
mtu
name_assign_type
netdev_group
operstate
phys_port_id
phys_port_name
phys_switch_id
power
queues
speed
statistics
subsystem
tx_queue_len
type
uevent
```

---

**Answer to the edited question:**

To get the interface name along with index:

`grep`:

```
ip addr | grep -o '^[0-9]\+:[^:]\+'
```

`sed`:

```
ip addr | sed -nE 's/^([[:digit:]]+:[^:]+).*/\1/p'
```

For each interface directory in `/sys/class/net/`, you can read the file `ifindex`. For example for interface `eth0`, the index file is:

```
/sys/class/net/eth0/ifindex
```

Comment: @enderland Each of the network devices listed is in fact a directory.  Within the directory is `ifindex` which is the index that you are after.